# Finding the index of beginning and end of a matched string in a word array

Tags: python

I would like to find a string match from an array of words, and get the index.

my variables

```
myString = "I heard a tapping"
wordList = ['Soon', 'again', 'I', 'heard', 'a', 'tapping', 'somewhat', 'louder', 'than', 'before']
```

The index I'm looking for, for this example is 2 and 5
I honestly don't even know where to begin

Comment: You're probably looking for [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)

Comment: I think this is quite straightforward. You need to show us some code and tell the issue you are facing.

Comment: The last element of the wordList array should be 'before'

Comment: Does the range from 2 to 5 have to contain all the words in `myString` in order?

Comment: yes, I was looking for an exact match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the string into a list.

Then search `wordList` for a slice that matches this.

```
myString = "I heard a tapping"
wordList = ['Soon', 'again', 'I', 'heard', 'a', 'tapping', 'somewhat', 'louder', 'than', 'before']
stringList = myString.split()
listLen = len(stringList)
for start in range(len(wordList)-listLen):
    if wordList[start:start+listLen] == stringList:
        end = start + listLen - 1
        print(start, end)
        break
else:
    print("Not found")
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use index and iterate through `myString`

which when split looks like
`['I', 'heard', 'a', 'tapping']`

**Using "in"**

```
indexes = [wordList.index(words) for words in myString.split() if words in wordList]
```

The above will iterate through `myString` and check if any word is in `wordList`. If so it will append the index value to a new list called `indexes`.

**output**

```
[2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Another way you could accomplish this is by using enumerate

```
indexes = [count for count,elements in enumerate(wordList) if elements in myString]
```

**output**

```
[2, 3, 4, 5]
```

**Using enumerate**

**Edit**
Because you are looking for the start and end you can just index the output lists like `list[0]` (first) and `list[-1]`(last)

Comment: This will find the words anywhere in the `wordList`. I thought he was looking for the start and end of a slice that matches `myString`

Answer (score 0):

Add to @BuddyBobiii's answer:

You can try using:

```
def findStringInWordArray(string, wordArray):
    a = [wordList.index(words) for words in myString.split() if words in wordList]
    return [a[0], a[-1]]
```

Then you can use it:

```
myString = "I heard a tapping"
wordList = ['Soon', 'again', 'I', 'heard', 'a', 'tapping', 'somewhat', 'louder', 'than', 'before']
findStringInWordArray(string, wordArray)
```

You will get `[2,5]` as the first index and the last index